# Does updating Cocoapods update in all app versions?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, cocoapods-app

I am using Cocoapods to manage my Admob/Google ad-related frameworks.
My pod file is as follows:

```
target 'SKGameTest' do
   use_frameworks!
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
end
```

I have updated Firebase and Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK using the Cocoapods app. Now that these frameworks have been updated, will all current versions of my app use these latest frameworks? Or will my app users have to download a new update containing these updated frameworks? If the last option (downloading a new update for the app) is true, then this would be really annoying as you would have to release a new update for your app each time Google updates their SDKs.

Please explain to me about how this all works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through some testing and have discovered that updating Cocoapods will not update all versions of the app (unfortunately). When updating your SDKs you will need to release a new version with it.